# Batik error when animating SVG element along a path

Tags: java, animation, svg, batik

I'm getting a NullPointerException (caught by Batik and spit out as "Error:   n tries to animate an element along a path.
I've tracked it down to a Point2D not being created because it's at -0.3 * the path length.
That's happening because of a negative timestep.

I'm wondering if this is something within my control?
Could someone take a look at the XML and see if I messed up?

I simplified some of the paths, but I'm trying to animate to a certain percentage along the path and then have it freeze:

```
<path fill="#ffffff" d="M14.25,-2.5 A2.5,2.5 0 1,1 14.25,2.5 L5.75,2.5 z" stroke-width="1.0" opacity="0.0" transform="translate(0.0,0.0) rotate(0.0,0,0) scale(1.0)" stroke="#000000">

<animateMotion dur="1.0" rotate="auto-reverse" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.0" path="M1212.3,273.5 C1001.2,509.3 452.1,480.7 266.7,224.3 " min="0.0" calcMode="paced" max="0.47916282407407407"/>
</path>

<text x="14.0" y="20.0" style="font-family:Droid Sans Mono; font-size:12.0; color:#000000; font-weight:bold; " opacity="0.0" transform="rotate(0.0,14.0,20.0) ">
A6EMF
<animateMotion dur="1.0" rotate="0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.0" path="M1212.3,273.5 C1001.2,509.3 452.1,480.7 266.7,224.3 " min="0.0" calcMode="paced" max="0.47"/>
</text>
```